# Referring to a value by row position with dplyr

Tags: r, apply, dplyr

I have `df` that have 12 columns:

```
df<-read.table(header=T,text="V1    V2       V3         V4             V5 V6   V7       V8       V9    V10  V11 V12
 A01 10378809 10379882 Contig1401|m.3412 101 -  10378809 10379882 255,0,0  1 1073   0
 A01 10469105 10469293 Contig1755|m.4465  48  + 10469105 10469293 255,0,0  2  188   0
 A01 10469429 10469630 Contig1755|m.4465   5  + 10469429 10469630 255,0,0  NA  201  0")
```

First I want to group them by contig and then generate the following values for 12th column. I figured out how to do this with `dplyr` but I have some errors.

```
as.data.frame(df %.% group_by(V4) %.% summarise(V12=apply(df[2], 2, function(x)x-x[1])))
```

The error:

`Error in summarise_impl(.data, named_dots(...), environment()) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name`.

For each group I want to subtract the 2nd value from the 1st value from 2nd column. I can do this easily if there are only 2 rows (max-min) but if there are more than 2 then I will miss the middle rows.

So I thought I will write a function and insert into `dplyr` but it seems I cannot use my own function with `dplyr`.

Here is the final output I need:

```
V1       V2       V3                V4  V5 V6       V7       V8      V9 V10  V11 V12
1 A01 10378809 10379882 Contig1401|m.3412 101  - 10378809 10379882 255,0,0   1 1073   0
2 A01 10469105 10469293 Contig1755|m.4465  48  + 10469105 10469293 255,0,0   2  188   0
3 A01 10469429 10469630 Contig1755|m.4465   5  + 10469429 10469630 255,0,0  NA  201 324
```

Comment: In your code, you subtract the first value from all values, not only from the second. What is the expected result for your example?

Comment: May be i am wrong. But i want to substract the 2nd value from the first value for each unique V4 column. I can do this easily if there are two but can't do if there are multiple ones. I edited my question to include the expected output. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %.% 
  group_by(V4) %.% 
  mutate(V12 = V2 - V2[1])
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Easy way around with dplyr. Thanks
Upendra

Comment: You can also use `first(V2)`. No advantage here, but in other situations it can be useful to define what you mean by "first"